# How can I show a tag description, using 'slug' rather than 'id'

Tags: tags

I'm currently using 'echo tag_description()' to show a tag description.

Is there an alternative whereby I can use the tag slug rather than ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the tag ID first. You can get the tag ID from the slug using the [`get_term_by()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_by/) function:

```
$tag = get_term_by( 'slug', 'tag-slug-here', 'post_tag' );

echo tag_description( $tag->term_id );
```